# Azure Form Recognizer URL error in my AuraQuantic Rest API

Tags: json, rest, azure-web-app-service, glowcode

I am creating an API in the `AuraQuantic` installation, it is to read documents with the AI of Azure Document Intelligence, a PDF document must be uploaded which, through Post, the text is read and with a GET the desired information is obtained of that PDF, but although it seems to read the Post and the GET without any problem, it does not extract the data and the JSON State remains empty. Checking the event viewer I see the following message:

> RestWebException.
>
> Body: {"error":{"code":"NotFound","message":"Resource not found.","innererror":{"code":"OperationNotFound","message":"The requested operation was not found. The identifier may be invalid or the operation may have expired."}}}. Status: Not Found. Message: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found..

You should know that it is a Azure free subscription, and that it has proven data not only in Spanish but in English, it also has a single page.

I have the correct region in my Azure, as indicated in the documentation, in the post I have the URL: https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/formrecognizer/documentModels/prebuilt-document:analyze?pages=1&locale=en- US&stringIndexType=textElements&api-version=2023-07-31
and in the GET I have the URL: [https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/formrecognizer/documentModels/prebuilt-read/analyzeResults/[3_result_id]?api-version=2023-02-28-preview](https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/formrecognizer/documentModels/prebuilt-read/analyzeResults/%5B3_result_id%5D?api-version=2023-02-28-preview)
The JSON of my response must be mapped, and I did it like this:

```
{
    "status":"3_json_status",
    "analyzeResult":{
       "documentResults###SingularFields":[
          {
             "docType":"3_Kps_JB-docType",
             "fields":{
                "Kps_Request":{
                   "text":"3_Kps_Request"
                },
                "Kps_Identification":{
                   "text":"Kps_Identification"
                },
                "Kps_Location":{
                   "text":"3_Kps_Place"
                },
                "Kps_Date":{
                   "text":"3_Kps_Date"
                },
                "Kps_NumeroPolizaColectiva":{
                   "text":"3_Kps_NumeroPolizaColectiva"
                },
                "Kps_Taker":{
                   "text":"3_Kps_Tomador"
                }
             }
          }
       ]
    }
}
```